# pandas keyerror with enumerate over pytorch dataloader

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pytorch, torchvision

### Introduction

I'm trying to load images according by accessing the names from a pandas dataframe which contains the list of paths. I have implemented a custom dataset where I load the pandas dataframe from a csv file using pandas.read_csv()

### Code excerpts

The dataset class:

```
class aDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, img_dir, csv_file, teacher_transform=None, student_transform=None):
        self.img_dir = img_dir
        self.image_list = pd.read_csv(csv_file, names=['path'], index_col=False)
        self.teacher_transform=teacher_transform
        self.student_transform=student_transform
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_list.index)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        teach_image_path = os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.image_list[idx][2:])
        teach_image = read_image(teach_image_path)
        image_iden = "/".join(teach_image_path.split("/")[:-1])
        iden_list = random.sample(os.listdir(image_iden), 100)
        temp_iden_list = [os.path.join(image_iden, i) for i in iden_list]
        iden_list = temp_iden_list
        iden_list.append(teach_image_path)
        student_image = read_image(random.choice(iden_list))
        teach_image = self.teacher_transform(teach_image)
        student_image = self.student_transform(student_image)
        return teach_image, student_image
```

Code for dataloader:

```
train = aDataset(train_img_dir, train_csv_file, teacher_transform=teacher_transform, student_transform=student_transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=BATCHSIZE, num_workers=NUM_WORKERS, shuffle=True)
```

here, NUM_WORKERS=0, BATCHSIZE=64

### CSV Format

The csv is of the following format:

```
./train/n000156/0299_01.jpg
./train/n000156/0352_01.jpg
./train/n000156/0223_01.jpg
./train/n000156/0072_01.jpg
./train/n000156/0088_01.jpg
./train/n000156/0024_02.jpg
./train/n000156/0139_01.jpg
.
.
.
```

The CSV file has 523649 lines in it.

### Error

However, I am getting the following error immediately after I start the training:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/starc52/miniconda3/envs/p3ver/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 453054

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "verMini.py", line 331, in <module>
    for iter_num, (teacher_images, student_images) in tqdm(enumerate(trainloader)):
  File "/home/starc52/miniconda3/envs/p3ver/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1185, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/home/starc52/miniconda3/envs/p3ver/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/starc52/miniconda3/envs/p3ver/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 561, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/starc52/miniconda3/envs/p3ver/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/starc52/miniconda3/envs/p3ver/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "verMini.py", line 74, in __getitem__
    teach_image_path = os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.image_list[idx][2:])
  File "/home/starc52/miniconda3/envs/p3ver/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3455, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/starc52/miniconda3/envs/p3ver/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 453054
```

### Suspected Bug

The code seems to stop because of an error at a random key each time I run it. There is a issue with the integration of pandas with the enumerate function.

Any direction/hint would be helpful. Thank you in advance!

### Solution

I changed the line `self.image_list[idx][2:]` to `self.image_list.loc[idx, 'path']` and it started working. I have no clue why it didn't work before, however. This stupid issue took me a day to figure out.

Comment: Can you check if the problem is indeed related to the num workers setting `NUM_WORKERS=0`?

Comment: @Berriel Umm no, I set NUM_WORKERS to 0, but the error still occurred. However, I'm still unable to pinpoint where it is going wrong. :(

Comment: I would update the question with the `NUM_WORKERS=0` case. Removing the unnecessary complexity of a question is always a good thing around here. Don't forget to update the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you replace `self.image_list[idx][2:]` with `self.image_list['path'][idx]`?

Comment: Please check the post again, I replaced ```self.image_list[idx][2:]``` with ```self.image_list.loc[idx, 'path'][2:]``` and it worked